# Blob trigger not waking up the docker container

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-instances, azure-blob-trigger

I have two functions in my container: one with a blob trigger and another one with a HTTP trigger. Runtime version is 4.28.4.4:

[image: Function container]

The managed environment is "Consumption only".

[image: Managed environment]

When I add a blob to my storage, hours go by without the function being triggered.

Then I call the HTTP function (a simple function that just returns "hello") and all my pending blobs get processed.

When the blob finally triggers, it executes without errors:

[image: Blob triggered]

Bellow is my HTTP trigger code:

```cs
[FunctionName("SayHello")]
public static IActionResult Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    var message = "Hello!";
    return new OkObjectResult(message);
}
```

Blob trigger:

```cs
[FunctionName("ProcessJpegImage")]
public static async Task RunAsync(
    [BlobTrigger(Containers.JpgExportProcessing + "/{name}", Connection = "[REDACTED]")] Stream inputBlob,
    string name,
    IDictionary<string, string> metadata,
    ILogger log)
{
    // ... processing code
}
```

I have the container name in another class:

```cs
public static class Containers
{
    public const string JpgExportProcessing = "jpg-export-processing";
    // ... more containers
}
```

My `host.json` is the default:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the in-process model for the function. Here's a part of the csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- ... files to copy to output/publish -->
</Project>
```

I'm guessing the HTTP trigger wakes the container up, but the blob trigger doesn't. What can I do about it?

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried and which runtime stack you are using?

Comment: @Pavan I have updated the question with the information you requested.

Comment: In the above you mentioned not waking up in docker but you didn't gave info about docker which you have tried? And where you have stucked?

Answer (score 0):

> When I add a blob to my storage, hours go by without the function being triggered.
> Then I call the HTTP function (a simple function that just returns "hello") and all my pending blobs get processed.

I have created http trigger and blob trigger functions with runtime stack dotnet.

By using below code and configuration I am able to access the blobs in storage account container without accessing the http function.

**Blob trigger function code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AzureFunctionsDemo
{
    public class ProcessJpegImage
    {
        [FunctionName("ProcessJpegImage")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("pavan/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

**Http trigger function code:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class SayHello
{
    [FunctionName("SayHello")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var message = "Hello!";
        return new OkObjectResult(message);
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "your-storage account conn-string",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
}
}
```

When I ran the above function, it successfully processed all blobs in the container.

**Output:**

[image]

After I accessed the HTTP function URL, I received the following output:

[image]